# spanning tree of a graph of minimum degree three

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Does each graph of minimum degree three admit a spanning tree whose vertices have degree three (exactly) except the leaves (degree one)?

Comment: I guess you mean **connected** graph of minimum degree $3$; non-connected graphs don't have spanning trees. If every vertex of the spanning tree has odd degree ($1$ or $3$), the number of vertices must be even by the "handshake" lemma. For a counterexample to your question, take any connected graph of minimum degree $3$ with an odd number of vertices, say $K_5-e$. By the way, your question is off topic for this site, next time try [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's even false for regular connected graphs of degree three; there is a counterexample with ten vertices.

Answer (score 2):

No graph with an odd number of vertices can have all degrees odd so any connected graph with an odd number of vertices and minimum degree $3$ is a counterexample.

There are at least two $8$ vertex counter examples which are regular of degree $3$. One is the skeleton of a cube and another is drawn below. In either case a spanning tree would use $7$ edges so the degrees would be eight values with total sum $14.$ This would have to be $3+3+3+1+1+1+1+1$ if no vertices had degree $2$. It is pretty easy to see that this can not be done. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Consider the following construction:

Take $4$ disjoint copies of $K_3$ and add a new special vertex and connect it to every other vertex.  You get a graph $G$ on $13$ vertices and $24$ edges. The special vertex has a degree of $12$ and every other vertex has a degree of $3$ in $G$. But,
in any tree of $G$ the special vertex has degree of at least $4$.